# Why do I get a KeyError in this Mage Data Pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, pipeline, geopandas

I am attempting to enrich a dataset with zip codes from the Chicago Data Portal. The chicago crimes dataset can be found at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-Present/ijzp-q8t2 and the geographic data for zip codes can be found at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-ZIP-Codes/gdcf-axmw

Concerning the shape file, I downloaded the geojson, saved it to github and loaded the file into a Mage data loader as a GeoPandas Dataframe. Please see the code for the following:

1. Load the Crimes dataset for 2023 as a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
if 'data_loader' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import data_loader
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test


@data_loader
def load_data_from_api(**kwargs):
    url='https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/ijzp-q8t2.csv?$limit=400000'
    app_token = 'You May Need Your Own APP Token'
    year="2023"
    headers = {
        "id": "id",
        "case_number": "case_number",
        "date": "date",
        "block":"block",
        "iucr": "iucr",
        "primary_type": "primary_type",
        "description": "description",
        "location_descrpition": "location_descrpition",
        "arrest": "arrest",
        "domestic": "domestic",
        "beat": "beat",
        "district": "district",
        "ward": "ward",
        "community_area": "community_area",
        "fbi_code": "fbi_code",
        "x_coordinate": "x_coordinate",
        "y_coordinate": "y_coordinate",
        "year": "year",
        "updated_on": "updated_on",
        "latitude": "lat",
        "longitude": "lng",
        "location": "location"
        }
    # Add the year as a query parameter in the API request
    params = {
        '$$app_token': app_token,
        'year': year
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Read the CSV data from the response
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text), sep=',')

        df.rename(columns=headers, inplace=True)

        return df
    else:
        # Handle error cases
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data for year {year}. Status code: {response.status_code}")

    return df


@test
def test_output(output, *args) -> None:
    """
    Template code for testing the output of the block.
    """
    assert output is not None, 'The output is undefined'
```

The output is a Pandas DataFrame that with a portion of the DataFrame in this picture

[image]

2. Load the Chicago Zip Code geojson as a geopandas dataframe:

```
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import requests
from shapely.geometry import Point

if 'data_loader' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import data_loader
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test


@data_loader
def get_geojson_data(**kwargs):
    """
    Template code for loading data from any source.

    Returns:
        Anything (e.g. data frame, dictionary, array, int, str, etc.)
    """
    # Specify your data loading logic here

    access_token = 'access token if you have a private github repository'
    raw_file_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github_username/Chicago_Crime/main/chicago_boundaries_zipcodes.geojson"
    
    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw'
    }

    response = requests.get(raw_file_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        geojson_data_str = response.text
        geojson_data = json.loads(geojson_data_str)
        
        # Convert GeoJSON to GeoDataFrame
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson_data['features'])
        
        return gdf
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve the file. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        
    return gdf


@test
def test_output(output, *args) -> None:
    """
    Template code for testing the output of the block.
    """
    assert output is not None, 'The output is undefined'
```

The output of this geopandas dataframe is:

[image]

My goal is to return a zip code in the Chicago Crimes Pandas DataFrame. I attempted the following code but get a key error. I am not sure what is going on as I know I output the 'lng' column from the dataframe df,

3. See code and traceback.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd


if 'transformer' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import transformer
if 'test' not in globals():
    from mage_ai.data_preparation.decorators import test


@transformer
def transform(df, gdf, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Template code for a transformer block.

    Args:
        df: DataFrame from the parent block
        gdf: GeoDataFrame containing geometry (polygons) and zip codes
        args: Output from any additional upstream blocks (if applicable)

    Returns:
        DataFrame with added 'zip_code' column
    """

    # Create Point geometries from latitude and longitude columns in df
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["lng"], df["lat"])]

    # Create a GeoDataFrame from df with the geometry
    df_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)

    # Initialize an empty list to store the zip codes
    zip_codes = []

    # Iterate through each row in df_geo
    for index, row in df_geo.iterrows():
        point = row["geometry"]
        
        # Iterate through each row in gdf to find if the point is within any polygon
        for gdf_index, gdf_row in gdf.iterrows():
            if point.within(gdf_row["geometry"]):
                zip_codes.append(gdf_row["zip"])
                break  # Stop searching once a match is found
        else:
            zip_codes.append(None)  # Append None if no match is found

    # Add the 'zip_code' column to df_geo
    df_geo["zip_code"] = zip_codes

    # Return the GeoDataFrame with the 'zip_code' column
    return df_geo

@test
def test_output(output, *args) -> None:
    """
    Template code for testing the output of the block.
    """
    assert output is not None, 'The output is undefined'
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key)

   3652         try:

-> 3653             return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

   3654         except KeyError as err:


/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()


/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()


pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()


pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()


KeyError: 'lng'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/c/data_engineering_with_python/311_project/transformers/zip_codes_1.py in transform(df, gdf, *args, **kwargs)

     27 

     28     # Create Point geometries from latitude and longitude columns in df

---> 29     geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["lng"], df["lat"])]

     30 

     31     # Create a GeoDataFrame from df with the geometry


/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __getitem__(self, key)

   1473         return a GeoDataFrame.

   1474         """

-> 1475         result = super().__getitem__(key)

   1476         # Custom logic to avoid waiting for pandas GH51895

   1477         # result is not geometry dtype for multi-indexes


/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)

   3759             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:

   3760                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)

-> 3761             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

   3762             if is_integer(indexer):

   3763                 indexer = [indexer]


/c/data_engineering_with_python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key)

   3653             return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

   3654         except KeyError as err:

-> 3655             raise KeyError(key) from err

   3656         except TypeError:

   3657             # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise


KeyError: 'lng'
```